# Does the tsu つ counter have a kanji associated with it?

Tags: kanji, counters

I can't seem to find anything online or in any dictionary.

My conclusion is that there is no kanji but can anyone confirm this?

Is there an archaic version that has gone out of use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're talking about 一つ、二つ、三つ、etc...

According to [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%AE%87), "箇" is defined as:

- Counter for the hito-futa-mi counting system (forming hitotsu, futatsu, mitsu, and misoji, yasoji, etc.)

Other forms of this kanji include 個 and 个 as notated on the dictionary entry itself.

Comment: In case anyone wanted something more authoritative than jisho, the definition in Koujien for つ as a counter also lists ͡箇 and 個.

Comment: @kouichi But is 個 not ''ko'' ?

Comment: @Kantura it is. If you wrote 一個, I would expect 100% of people would read that as いっこ. In Koujien they offered the example of ひと箇 or ひと個, but I don't expect anyone would actually use that today. It's just that such a way to write it has existed.